# Is there an easier way to send ENTER key in GNU Screen?

Tags: unix, gnu-screen

Currently I am using a script to spawn a daemon:

```
screen -r user -X stuff "spawn daemon"
screen -r user -X eval "stuff \015"
```

Is there an easier way to send the enter key ("\015"), or in fact a better way of doing this? (I have to use screen.)

I assume that because I'm not attaching the screen, I won't be able to get the outcome/output of the "spawn daemon" command. Is that correct?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I always do it like this:

```
screen -r user -X stuff "spawn daemon^M"
```

where I get the ^M by hitting ctrl-v, then Enter, on the command line.  In bash and vim, ctrl-v can be used to escape characters like Enter that would otherwise have a special effect.

Comment: Note: you can even write "stuff ^m", as in "caret character, M character", and `screen` will transform this into a single Enter character (`\x0D`).

Comment: `\r` also works, e.g. `screen -X stuff "echo 'hello world'\r"`. ... `^M` and `\r` are different notations for the same thing: a *carriage return*. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes

Comment: I've read this in some SO articles now - but for me, any combination of `^M`, `^m`,  `\n`, `\r`, ... just type this to my session, so it reads `/my/script.sh\r` then, but don't execute pressing enter. I'm on MacOS 13.5.2 and recent `screen` 4.00.03 from Homebrew.

Answer (score 4):

As for the second question, you can enable logging, and read from the log file.

Comment: Thanks. I'd forgotten about that.

Answer (score 4):

This solution is working in my case:

```
screen -r user -X stuff "spawn daemon$(printf \\r)"
```

Comment: Quite elegant. Especially because you can store this character in a variable `n="$(printf \\r)"` and later use it writing just `$n`

Answer (score 1):

Sending CR:

```
echo -e "Some text\015" > /dev/pts/1
```

Sending LF:

```
echo -e "Some text\012" > /dev/pts/1
```

Replace the number in device path with actual screen number.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the solutions mentioned here and in similar SO threads, do not work.
I'm on MacOS 13.5.2 and use a recent `screen` version 4.00.03 from Homebrew.

I want to spawn a screen session in the background and later in my scripts, execute a command in that. So this is what I do:

```bash
screen -dmS myLongRunning
screen -S myLongRunning -p 0 -X stuff "/path/to/script $*\n"
```

When I attach to that session then, it reads exactly that typed to the command prompt, but does not "send" the Enter-equivalent:

`/path/to/script ''\n`

This is the same, no matter which of the otherwise mentioned control-characters I use. I tried with:

- `\n`
- `\r`
- `^M`
- `^m`
- `\015`

The only variant I found working was the one mentioned by [anthon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1307905/anthon) :

```bash
screen -S myLongRunning -p 0 -X stuff "/path/to/script $*$(printf \\r)"
```

does the trick!